# How to config Hidden Layers in DNNClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, classification

Im new to Tensorflow&ML and following this example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn

It works very well until change `hidden_units` parameter here:

```
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                        hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                        n_classes=3,
                                        model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")
```

When i try anything, for example `hidden_units = [20, 40, 20]` or `hidden_units = [20]` it throws an error.

I tried to find out on my own but unsuccessfully so far and thought someone here can help.
The question is how to chose a number of hidden layers for DNN Classifier and why two my examples above do not work?

Here is a full code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import urllib

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

IRIS_TRAINING = "iris_training.csv"
IRIS_TRAINING_URL = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv"

IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"
IRIS_TEST_URL = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_test.csv"

if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TRAINING):
  raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TRAINING_URL).read()
  with open(IRIS_TRAINING,'wb') as f:
    f.write(raw)

if not os.path.exists(IRIS_TEST):
  raw = urllib.request.urlopen(IRIS_TEST_URL).read()
  with open(IRIS_TEST,'wb') as f:
    f.write(raw)

# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TEST,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)

# Specify that all features have real-value data
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=4)]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                            n_classes=3,
                                            model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")
# Define the training inputs
def get_train_inputs():
  x = tf.constant(training_set.data)
  y = tf.constant(training_set.target)

  return x, y

# Fit model.
classifier.fit(input_fn=get_train_inputs, steps=2000)
# Define the test inputs
def get_test_inputs():
  x = tf.constant(test_set.data)
  y = tf.constant(test_set.target)

  return x, y

# Evaluate accuracy.
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=get_test_inputs,
                                     steps=1)["accuracy"]

print("\nTest Accuracy: {0:f}\n".format(accuracy_score))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it,
if `model_dir` is not specified than moel works just fine with new `hidden_units`

Comment: You can include model_dir. But it probably shouldn't begin with "/" unless your program has permission to write to the filesystem root.